# How to compute the cross correlation of two fuctions

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation

I am trying to implement Matlab's cross correlation function but I can't seem to replicate the results obtained when using Matlab's built in function "xcorr".

Documentation for xcorr can be found [HERE](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html).

Looking at the Matlab documentation it seems as though the cross correlation is implemented as

$$
  R_{xy}[m] =  \left.\begin{cases} \sum_{n=0}^{N - m - 1} x[n + m] y[n]
& m \geq 0\\ \\ R_{yx}[-m] & m < 0\\ \end{cases} \right\}
$$

Or equivalently as

$$
  R_{xy}[m] =  \left.\begin{cases} \sum_{n=1}^{N - m} x[n + m] y[n]
& m \geq 0\\ \\ \sum_{n=1}^{N + m} y[n - m] x[n] & m < 0\\ \end{cases} \right\}
$$

if x and y have indexes starting at 1.The result will then be C, where

$$
  C(m) = R_{xy}(m - N) \hspace{1cm} \text{for} \hspace{1cm} m = 1, 2,...,2N - 1. 
$$

The implementation of this formula in Matlab is shown below:

```
function [result] = myXCorr(A , B)
%Implementation of the Cross Coorelation Function

N = size(A,2);
M = size(B,2);
result = zeros(1, N + M - 1 );
len = size(result,2);

for m = 1 : len  
   arg = (m - N); 

   if(arg < 0)
       negativeCondition = 1;
       limit = N + arg;
   else
       negativeCondition = 0;
       limit = N - arg;
   end

   for n = 1:limit
           if(negativeCondition == 0)
            result(m) = result(m) + A(arg + n) + B(n);
           else
            result(m) = result(m) + A(n) + B(n - arg);
           end
   end
end

end
```

This implementation does not produce the same results as Matlab and I can't seem to find out  what the error is.The plots of the autocorrelation's are shown below.

```
A = 1:1:10;
B = 1:1:10;

myResult = myXCorr(A,B);
mResult = xcorr(A,B);

lag = -9:1:9;

plot(lag, myResult);
plot(lag, mResult);
```

Autocorrelation using my function:

[image: myXCorr.jpg]

Autocorrelation using "xcorr":

[image: xcorr.jpg]

Does anyone know what 'm doing wrong here? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you succeed to find the correct matlab for this ? I really need this :D

Comment: The accepted answer is correct, I added the A and B values instead of multiplying them.

Comment: Ok thank you, its working now, but I want to create a function like xcorr (= cross- and auto-correlation).
And so with this function, I want to be able to make the cross correlation when two inputs vectors are used (x,y) (This part is ok with your program) but I also want to make the auto-correlation if only one vector is present in the list of arguments... Do you know if its possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the loop where you compute your result vector, you should be multiplying the A and B values instead of adding them up.

Comment: Nice catch! Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

```
for n = 1:limit
      if (negativeCondition==0)
        result(m) = result(m) + A(n) * B(n - arg);
      else
        result(m) = result(m) + A(arg + n) * B(n);
      end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to DSP SE. Generally code-only answers are considered low quality. Any chance of elaborating and explaining?